# Compiling Apache mod_ssl for different target hardware (hardware capability unsupported SSE2 error)

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris, openssl, mod-ssl

I am building and packaging the following on one machine (the "build" machine) and attempting to install and use on other machines ("target" machines) some of which have different processors.

- OpenSSL 0.9.8l
- Apache 2.2.14
- Tomcat Connectors 1.2.28

The problem, as far as I can tell, is that the build machine has more CPU capabilities than the target machine resulting in binaries that are not executable on the target machine.  I have attempted to use configure and compiler flags to disable use of the offending instructions without luck.

Ultimately I get this error:

```
$ ./apachectl start
```

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /usr/local/apache-2.2.14/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: ld.so.1: httpd: 
fatal: /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8: hardware capability unsupported: 
0x1000 [ SSE2 ]
```

Here is my complete build process.  Full output from each command can be viewed [here](http://sites.google.com/site/gchris/home/a).  I can't link to them each directly since I don't have enough SF rep.

**The Build Machine**

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/opt/sfw/bin:/usr/sbin

$ isainfo -v
32-bit i386 applications
        pause sse2 sse fxsr mmx cmov sep cx8 tsc fpu 

$ uname -a
SunOS bsiausstgdb02 5.10 Generic_120012-14 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

**The Target Machine**

```
$ isainfo -v
32-bit i386 applications
        sse fxsr mmx cmov sep cx8 tsc fpu 

$ uname -a
SunOS bsiausdevweb01 5.10 Generic_120012-14 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

**Compile OpenSSL 0.9.8l**

```
$ CC=/usr/bin/cc
$ export CC

$ CFLAGS="-xarch=sse"
$ export CFLAGS

$ ./Configure \
solaris-x86-cc \
shared \
no-asm \
no-sse2 \
-xarch=sse \
--openssldir=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8l
```

*view full output:* 
openssl-configure.txt

```
$ make && make test
```

*view full output:* 
openssl-make-and-test.txt

```
$ sudo make install
```

*view full output:* 
openssl-make-install.txt

**Compile Apache 2.2.14**

```
$ CC=/usr/bin/cc
$ export CC

$ CFLAGS="-xarch=sse"
$ export CFLAGS

$ ./configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/apache-2.2.14 \
--with-mpm=prefork \
--enable-so \
--enable-unique-id=shared \
--enable-rewrite=shared \
--enable-spelling=shared \
--enable-info=shared \
--enable-headers=shared \
--enable-deflate=shared \
--enable-expires=shared \
--enable-unique-id=shared \
--enable-speling=shared \
--enable-ssl=shared \
--with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl
```

*view full output:* 
apache-configure.txt

```
$ make
```

*view full output:* 
apache-make.txt

```
$ sudo make install
```

*view full output:* 
apache-make-install.txt

**Compile Tomcat Connectors 1.2.28**

```
$ CC=/usr/bin/cc
$ export CC

$ CFLAGS="-xarch=sse"
$ export CFLAGS

$ cd native
$ ./configure \
--with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
```

*view full output:* 
tomcat-connector-configure.txt

```
$ make
```

*view full output:* 
tomcat-connector-make.txt

```
$ sudo make install
```

*view full output:* 
tomcat-connector-make-install.txt

**Testing**

At this point everything will work on the build machine.  Once I package these files and install them on the target machine, I get this error when Apache is started with mod_ssl enabled.

```
$ ./apachectl start
```

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /usr/local/apache-2.2.14/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: ld.so.1: httpd: 
fatal: /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8: hardware capability unsupported: 
0x1000  [ SSE2 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this problem by building the packages on a machine with equivalent hardware to the target machine and using the Sun Studio CC compiler instead of gcc.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that I have done to successfully build and install the Apache httpd-2.4.10 and OpenSSL openssl-1.0.1j on Solaris 10.

1. Download following software
   openssl-1.0.1j.tar.gz
   httpd-2.4.10.tar.gz
   apr-1.5.1.tar.gz
   apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
   pcre-8.36.tar.gz
2. Verify Make and CC
   By default `gcc` is at `/usr/sfw/bin/gcc` and `make` is at `/usr/ccs/bin/make`

   Include following in the PATH
   `usr/local/ssl/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ccs/bin`

   Include following in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   `/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/ssl/lib`
3. Build and install openssl-1.0.1j
   Unzip and un-tar openssl-1.0.1j.tar.gz to `/usr/local/openssl-1.0.1j`
   Execute following commands in order. The shared parameter is very important so that it can be linked with httpd-2.4.10 build for SSL enabling.

   ```
   $ cd /usr/local/openssl-1.0.1j
   $ ./config shared
   $ make
   $ make test
   $ make install
   ```

   By default it installs openssl at /usr/local/ssl
4. Install pcre-8.36
   Unzip and un-tar pcre-8.36.tar.gz to /usr/local/ pcre-8.36

   Execute following commands in order

   ```
   $ cd /usr/local/ pcre-8.36
   $ ./configure 
   $ make
   $ make install
   ```

   By default, `make install` installs the package's commands under
   `/usr/local/bin`, include files under `/usr/local/include`, etc.
5. Build and install httpd-2.4.10

   Unzip and un-tar httpd-2.4.10.tar.gz to `/usr/local/httpd-2.4.10`

   Unzip and un-tar apr-1.5.1.tar.gz to `/usr/local/httpd-2.4.10/srclib`
   Rename /usr/local/apr-1.5.1 to `/usr/local/apr`

   Unzip and un-tar apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz to `/usr/local/httpd-2.4.10/srclib`
   Rename /usr/local/apr-util to `/usr/local/apr-util`

   Execute following commands in order

   ```
   $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --with-included-apr --enable-so –enable-ssl=shared --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
   $ make
   $ make install
   ```

   It installs it at `/usr/local/apache2`

The installation is complete. To enable SSL and Proxy, update `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` with uncommentting following lines

```
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so

LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Now you can work on httpd-ssl.conf as you usually do to complete your configuration